# Change content of one Struts 2 select tag dynamically

Tags: struts2, struts-tags, double-select

I have two Struts 2 `<s:select>` tags; one for the `country`, and another for the `state`:

```
<s:select label="country" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select country" list="country"       name="countryID" />

<s:select label="state" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select state" list="state"   name="stateID" />
```

When the `country` select changes I want to show only that country's states.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Struts2 `doubleselect` tag. It

> Renders two HTML select elements with second one changing displayed values depending on selected entry of first one.

```jsp
<s:doubleselect label="Select country/state" name="country" list="{'country1','other'}" doubleName="state" doubleList="top == 'country1' ? {'state1', 'state2'} : {'state3', 'state4'}" />
```

For the real example see [Struts 2 `<s:doubleselect>` example](https://www.w3schools.blog/struts-2-sdoubleselect-ui-tag).

Comment: i am retrieving my code from database please give me an example if possible

Comment: You can use jquery and json action. This is alternative.

Comment: @user3905650 For examples your should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16419015/573032) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17898392/573032) answer.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Do you mean like [this](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag#A_simple_Doubleselect_with_Topics)?

Comment: yes. it is also good to provide href and before topics or we can use $.getJson or $.change() jquery methods handcoded.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi There are hrefs, why do you need *before* topic? Wouldn't it be a bit difficult with _$.getJson or $.change() jquery methods_?

Comment: onChangeTopics, not before topics. Yes that would be little bit difficult but if they want to understand. may be as an alternative.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi The feature is available in the S2 and/or S2 plugins, why should OP use raw javascript and html to reinvent the wheel? Does OP has a special requirement to utilize jQuery events and/or Ajax? There's a lot of questions on SO (even in struts2 tag) that are implementing doubleselet feature using jQuery, this is not OP asked.

Comment: @user3905650 You are welcome! Seems we put some effort in discussion to this answer, is it really was so helpful? I was provided many links, did you follow them?