# struts2 with 3 dependent dropdowns without using ajax

Tags: struts2

I'm using Struts 2 and MySQL.

In my JSP I have 3 select controls:

```
<s:select list="country" name="country" onchange="getstate();" />
<s:select list="state"   name="state"   onchange="getcity();"  />
<s:select list="city"    name="city" />
```

In my action class:

```
public string displayDetails() { 
    getCountry();
    getState(getCountry());
    getCity(getState());
}
```

If I want to get state I have to access getCountry() method again. How can I avoid that call every time?

If I'm not adding all the action in one method I'm getting "list field is not filled" error.

Comment: What? What does `getCountry()` even do? Is it a simple property accessor? If so, why call it and do nothing with the results? What are those JavaScript methods? It's completely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: without using ajax means.you can use doubleselect in struts2.                                                     `http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sdoubleselect-example`

Comment: See [Change content of one Struts2 select tag dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25114191/573032).

Comment: if i have more than 4 dropdowns all are dependent its not possible to use <s:doubleselect>tag

Comment: even im trying to access json there also all the methods use to call...plz some one help me

Comment: Improve your question or you will get minus voting.

Comment: Provide some details that exactly what you are doing and what output do you want? we are not able to understand what you are asking.

Comment: if i have 10 drop down how can i fill onchange of previous selection using strut2 select tag and every time based on the selected data the value should fetch the details from the database. how can i achieve this